# Emacs can't connect to GNU archive

Tags: init-file, http

I'm having a very basic problem with getting my emacs to talk to the GNU package repository.

The contents of my .emacs are

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)
```

When I start up emacs, I see

```
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
```

When I do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then `M-x package-refresh-contents`, I get the following stacktrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents" "Bad Request")
  signal(file-error ("https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents" "Bad Request"))
  package--download-one-archive(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
  package--download-and-read-archives(nil)
  package-refresh-contents()
  funcall-interactively(package-refresh-contents)
  call-interactively(package-refresh-contents record nil)
  command-execute(package-refresh-contents record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-refre")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-refre")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

I originally was trying to connect to Melpa, but I saw I have this issue even working with just the GNU archive. I'm on Emacs 26.2, macOS 10.14.6.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Emacs 26.3 fixes this.

- https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=34341
- https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=36725

You should upgrade (26.2 to 26.3 is a very minor update; nothing should break); but if you genuinely cannot do that for some reason, then this might do the trick for you:

```
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
```

You could also consider installing 27.1, which is the latest release.

Comment: Thanks! Updated to latest (27.1) and it fixed it.